# MYSQL запрос и массив

Tags: массивы, php, база-данных, mysql

Добрый день. В ходе работы над приложением встала такая проблема. Имеется массив с уникальными значениями:

```
0 => 123456
1 => 234567
2 => 345678
3 => 664458...
```

Количество элементов неизвестно. Также имеется таблица:

```
id | user_id | name
```

Необходимо вывести из таблицы все значения, где user_id совпадает с каким-то элементом. Создавать вторую таблицу со значениями массива не подходит. И запрос SELECT с многочисленными WHERE тоже, т.к. массив может содержать более 1000 элементов.

Стоит использовать IN или есть какое-то другое решение?

Comment: У меня складывается впечатление, что в самой архитектуре Вашего приложения уже допущен серьезный просчет. То, о чем Вы говорите - это обычные связи по внешнему ключу, почему бы не использовать для этого саму БД? Если массив будет очень большой, то операции с ним получаться очень "дорогими", а вот выдергивать JOIN'ом связи из БД гараздо "дешевле". Хотя, может я чего-то не понял...

Comment: Потому что массив возвращает метод стороннег API.

Про JOIN я знаю

Comment: а откуда берутся эти идентификаторы пользователей? я думаю что задачу оттуда и надо решать.

Comment: Написал же, массив возвращается сторонним API

Comment: то у вас 1000 элементов, то млн... Стратегия поиска решения и от этого тоже зависит...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WEHRE IN(".implode(",", array()).")"
```

не подходит?

Comment: В принципе, я тоже о нем думал. Но как будет работать, если в таблице, скажем, миллион записей?

Comment: по поводу производительности ничего не могу сказать. Поискал в гугле (было лень), толком ничего не написано.

Comment: Из опыта скажу, что даже если обычной селект конкретной строки с заданным id при кол-ве записей >1млн, будет долгим. Такие таблицы нужно кешировать или иные методы оптимизации использовать.

Comment: Если вы собираетесь работать с массивами длиной > 1kk элементов, то PHP не лучший для этого инструмент.

Comment: для Zowie - Не факт! У меня как раз есть пример, где именно перенос обработки на PHP позволил сократить время обработки с 4 сек до 40мс!!!

Comment: @СергейВ. А переносили с 1с на PHP?)) Тогда возможно. Попробуйте компилируемые языки программирования, получите ускорение в десятки раз)

Answer (score 2):

Сформируйте временную(или не временную) из вашего массива
далее

```
SELECT <some_fields> FROM <TableInBase> INNER JOIN <TempOrNotTempTable> ON
<TableInBase>.user_id = <TempOrNotTempTable>.user_id
```

Comment: Временная таблица не вариант. Слишком много будет запросов и она просто упадет

Comment: Хотя  это почти тот же самый IN))))

Comment: Дык как часто меняется массив ваш?
Может стоит один раз сформировать данную таблицу из вашего массива

Comment: Придется формировать временную, т.к. значения массива могут меняться, а это значит, что после SELECT запроса еще придется удалять эту таблицу.

У каждого пользователя свой массив, следовательно, он непостоянен

Comment: ну уж времнную для каждого пользователя не обязательно, можно и одной обойтсь
просто в ней еще зафикачить поле client_code в котором лежит уникальное поле владельца массива

Comment: Ну, в общем, я попробую оба варианта

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно попробовать оптимизировать (сам не пробовал) следующим образом - сначала из массива получаем наименьшие и наибольшие значения. А далее строим запрос

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WEHRE id>=$min and $id=<$max and id IN(".implode(",", array()).")"
```

Хотя, возможно, лучше использовать и подзапрос

```
"SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `table` WEHRE id>=$min and $id=<$max ) as t1
WHERE t1.id IN(".implode(",", array()).")"
```

В общем, надо тестить)

Comment: наименьшее и наибольшее не подходит. Значения не упорядочены

Comment: разные по типу или что?

Comment: По значению. Ибо я больше не знаю, зачем использовать минимум и максимум

Comment: Смотри к примеру у тя в базе 10 млн записей - от 0 до 9 999 999
твой массив из 1000 значений к примеру, в котором ты находишь минимальное значение - например 5 000 000  и максимальное 9 000 000,
так вот может получится с помощью макс и мин ограничить поиск в самой базе, изначально выбрав из не этот кусок. Но нада смотреть как исполнятся запрос будет, в общем тестить нада

Answer (score 0):

Можно не нагружать SQL сервер, и сделать всё локально, например собрав строку значений:

```
IEnumerable<int> categoryes= new[]{8,9,21};
string text = String.Join(",", categoryes);
String.Format("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN({0})",text);
```